# extra e character is inserted before every character

Tags: insert, characters

I have a problem every so often where I accidentally hit a key combination (don't know what it is) and I get into a state where the letter e (sometimes it is another letter IIRC) is inserted before every normal character. Modifiers are ok like M-x or C-x, but not C-x b - it gets interpreted as C-x e. Backspace is also ok. I've checked my *Messages* buffer but don't see anything there (see pasted below). Is there somewhere else I could look or something else I could try to debug or undo when this happens? I would like to find a way out of it so I can undo it when I accidentally do it (having to quit emacs is a pain even with my session saved, since I lose all my active shell buffers and their histories - and my normal steps of saving them manually has a lot of backspacing to remove extra `e` chars).

```
Mark set
Mark saved where search started
Mark set
Grep finished (matches found)
Mark set [3 times]
After 0 kbd macro iterations: isearch-search: Keyboard macro terminated by a command ringing the bell [3 times]
Quit [3 times]
After 0 kbd macro iterations: isearch-search: Keyboard macro terminated by a command ringing the bell
Quit [4 times]
```

GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS appkit-1265.21 Version 10.9.5 (Build 13F34))
 of 2015-01-14 on pbuckleys-mbp.bos.dataxu.net

Comment: As soon as this happens next time, hit `C-h l` or `M-x view-lossage`. Hope that works even with the auto chars issue.

Comment: Does it only happen in Emacs? Does it happen when you run Emacs with `emacs -q` (i.e. without your customizations)?

Comment: It only happens in Emacs. And it only happens when I accidentally hit some key combination, usually after a couple months of running emacs. Since I'm not sure what is causing it, I can't start emacs with `-q` ahead of time, because I'd be without my customizations for an extended period.